# Angular Universal does not render data from API Requests

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

My Angular Universal application is only rendering the HTML in the template, but not any variables or data that is loaded from API requests.

I created a very simple test component:

HTML:

```html
<h1>ObjectID: #{{user?.id}}</h1>
```

Typescript:

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser(1).subscribe(user => this.user = user)
  }
}
```

The results from this if I look in the source of my page will be `<h1>ObjectID: #</h1>`. I'm using the [Universal Starter](https://github.com/enten/angular-universal/). Isn't the Angular Universal server suppose to wait for the `ngOnInit()` to finish loading?

Comment: Check if you don't have any error server side

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. My resolve data is not shown in the view source.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was serving my Angular app and my API app from 2 separate Docker containers, and the Server-Side-Rendered NodeJS app was trying to do the HTTP calls to the public url of the API container -- the problem with this is that a Docker container does not know the public url (e.g. 0.0.0.0:8000) of the other containers, it only knows the container names (e.g. http://backend).

This is only an issue during development, not during production because then it uses a real public domain.

The solution I did was to add a alias in my `etc/hosts` file on my local computer to 0.0.0.0, and then also adding the same alias in my `docker-compose.yml` file. So both my browser, and the container, can access the API on a custom hostname.

**etc/hosts on local machine**

```
0.0.0.0 api.local
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  ...
  backend:
    ...
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - "api.local"
```

All HTTP calls during development from both the client and the server side rendered app is done to `http://api.local/`